# JavaScript / высота контента.

Tags: javascript

Есть блок div, в нем много контента, его высота меняется в зависимости от количества контента.

Нужно сделать так: Что бы изначально высота блока div была в 50px, а при клике на нее, что бы ее высота(height) изменилась до, количества его контента.

Надеюсь идею поняли...

Т.е. содержимое блока изменяется, и сам блок нужно растягивать на полный размер контента.
Как это можно реализовать, через свойство scrollHeight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

что-то такое получилось =) http://jsfiddle.net/5U9pw/1/

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но нужно на чистом js

http://hashcode.ru/questions/308461/javascript-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: @VasyaVasya, итить-калатить, говорите сразу что вам нужно блть